# SharePoint site for TFS is still connecting to the old TFS url

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, tfs-2015

I have configured a lab environment database taken from a prod environment, now my sharepoint sites web part are still trying to connect to the other TFS URL. 
How to redirect them to the new TFS application server URL?

Comment: Did your SharePoint server and TFS server installed on the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , please check the related  SharePoint configuration of the tfs in administration console.
`Application tier --> SharePoint Web Applications` and  `Application tier --> Team project collection --> SharePoint site`.

If this configured correctly,since the web part still refer to the old SharePoint. It may be a **cache** issue, try to [clean the TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) both in your client machine and SharePoint server.

If the issue still exists, give a try with uninstalling the  TFS extensions for SharePoint and reinstall it, which may do the trick. More details please refer this thread: [Use the same SharePoint site for TFS that you have right now](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/upgrade-2013/use-same-sharepoint-site)

Comment: Application tier --> Team project collection --> SharePoint site was not done properly. Thank you very much for the help.